# Cant find Cell Identifier(No storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

Hi I hav an issue where I cant seem to find the cell identifier to put into my table. I have 5 files.I am new to xcode but I need to code without a storyboard for my school project.

I am following the tutorial here -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYmZ-4l0Yy4

ActiveCasesController.swift

```
//
//  ActiveCasesController.swift
//
//  Created by fypj on 29/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 fypj. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ActiveCasesController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let elements = ["horse", "cat", "dog", "potato","horse", "cat", "dog", "potato","horse", "cat", "dog", "potato"]


var acView = ActiveCasesView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupView()
    acView.tableView.delegate = self
    acView.tableView.dataSource = self
}

func setupView() {
    let mainView = ActiveCasesView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.acView = mainView
    self.view.addSubview(acView)
    acView.setAnchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return elements.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:ActiveCaseCellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! ActiveCaseCellView

    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellView.frame.height / 2

    cell.lblCell.text = elements[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


}
```

ActiveCasesView.swift

```
import UIKit

class ActiveCasesView: UIView{

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
    //scrollView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ACView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(mainView)
    mainView.frame = self.bounds
    mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
}
}
```

ACView.xib

[image]

ActiveCaseCellView.swift

```
import UIKit

class ActiveCaseCellView:UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblCell: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
}
```

ACViewCell.xib

[image]

Error Message

[image]

Image of me adding register not sure whether i added correctly..

[image]

Comment: It turns out I needed to change outlet from file owner to custom cell too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `.xib` file and drag and drop `UITableViewCell` not `UIView`.

[image]

After that select attribute inspector you will see cell identifier textbook where you need to set cell identifier

[image]

**Don't forget to register table view cell before using it!!**

```
self.tableView.registerClass(<YourCustomCellClass>, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

or

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "YourNibFileName", bundle: nil)

tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still am unable to run I have added            let nib = UINib(nibName: "ACViewCell", bundle: nil)
        
        acView.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell") but I now get the error "his class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellView"

Comment: have you registered cell.?

Comment: yea i registered the cell in view did load but I got the error  "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellView" in when I start it up

Comment: Your` ACView` is not `UITableViewCell`....`ActiveCaseCellView` is a table view cell...this is the reason you are getting a crash.

Comment: I have changed my stupid mistake... but now I am getting "Could not load NIB in bundle" ...

Comment: Pl. check it is in `your target -> Build Settings -> Copy Bundle Resources`...is it is not there then add it.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me... It is already in there but I am still getting the error

Comment: Have you specified custom class name to `ACView.xib`?

Comment: Hi I do not think I have done that could you please explain the process?

Comment: Select `ACView.xib`, Go to Identity Inspector, Make sure `View` is selected and after that in `Custom class` specify the custom class name `ACView`......and also do the same for your table view cell `ActiveCaseCellView`

Comment: I think you should search. for `Could not load NIB in bundle` error you will get lot of answers :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
use the cell identifier by selecting you cell in storyboard.
it must be same in viewcontroller and storyboard tableview cell.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` on your tableView to make it find the requred cells upon calling `dequeue...`.
You can set the reuse identifier in the xib or storyboard where your cell is defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set cell identifier in **Xib**
2. Register **Xib** with `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad` :

   ```
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ActiveCaseCellView", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
   ```